# CRTP causing segfault

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, crtp, pure-virtual

I have a pure virtual class `Interface`:

```
class Interface {
  public:
    virtual ~Interface() noexcept;
    virtual void open()=0;
    virtual void close()=0;
  protected:
    explicit Interface(const string params);
    string params_;
}
```

I then have an abstract class where I implement my business logic:

```
template<typename T>
class AbstractInterface : public Interface {
  public:
    void open() override;
    void close() override;
    void read_is_complete(const vector<byte_array>);
  protected:
    explicit AbstractInterface(const string params);
    virtual ~AbstractInterface() noexcept;
}
```

Then there is the implementation for the interface that uses CRTP for polymorphism:

```
class SPInterface : public AbstractInterface<SPInterface> {
  public:
    explicit SPInterface(const string params);
    virtual ~SPInterface() noexcept;
    void open();
    void close();
    void read_is_complete(const vector<byte_array> data);
}
```

I have a unit test where I create an instance of `SPInterface`:

```
unique_ptr<Interface> intf;
intf.reset(new SPInterface("aaa"));
```

Letting this get out of scope calls the destructor `AbstractInterface` which in turn calls the close method on `AbstractInterface` and then it segfaults on `this`:

```
template<typename T>
void AbstractInterface<T>::close() {
  static_cast<T *>(this)->close();
  params_ = "";
}
```

Which is confusing as I already created an instance of the class. lldb seems to confirm:

```
AbstractInterface<SPInterface>::close(this=<unavailable>)
```

Comment: Does it look safe to try to invoke a method of a derived class from the destructor of a base class?

Comment: I think you have a point there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Letting this get out of scope calls the destructor AbstractInterface which in turn calls the close method on AbstractInterface and then it segfaults on this:

```
template<typename T>
void AbstractInterface<T>::close() {
    static_cast<T *>(this)->close();
    params_ = "";
}
```

---

It seems that you are trying to invoke a method of a derived class from within the destructor of a base class.
This is not safe at all and a *segfault* is the way the executable has to tell you that it doesn't approve that. :-)

Even though CRTP allows you to invoke a member function that belongs to the derived class on a (let me say) *living object*, it doesn't change the way an object is destructed.
Do not forget that *bases and members are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of their constructor*.